# How to test multiple conditions together in Match / Case?

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I know how to use "|" to separate as an "or" for testing cases but this is a bit more than that.

I have 4 variables and each is a boolean. So I have a total of 16 states given each (as drawn out in a truth table)

I wrote the code for my blackjack program to manage testing actions but it does not seem to trigger any of the cases:

```
for x in range(10):
    myHandTotal = myHand.getTotal()   #gets total of current hand
    isSoft = myHand.isSoft            #gets whether the hand is soft (at least 1 ace as 11)
    hardAction = at.getHardAction(myHand, dealer) #gets hit or stand based on table (given soft hand)
    softAction = at.getSoftAction(myHand, dealer) #gets hit or stand based on table (given soft hand)
    print("Total: ", myHandTotal, " - isSoft: ", isSoft, " - getHardAction: ", hardAction, " - getSoftAction: ", softAction)
    match (myHandTotal < 21, isSoft, hardAction, softAction):
        case [True, True, "Stand", "Hit" | True, True, "Hit", "Hit"]:   #if hand is soft and soft table says hit
            myHand.draw1(deck)
            print("Should Hit")
            continue
        case [True, False, "Hit", "Hit" | True, False, "Hit", "Stand"]:  #if hand is hard and hard table says hit
            myHand.draw1(deck)
            print("Should Hit")
            continue
        case [False, True, "Stand", "Hit" | False, True, "Hit", "Hit" | False, False, "Hit", "Hit" | False, False, "Hit", "Stand" | False, True, "Stand", "Stand" | False, False, "Stand", "Stand" | False, True, "Hit", "Stand" | False, False, "Stand", "Hit"]:
            break #bust
        case [True, True, "Stand", "Stand" | True, True, "Hit", "Stand"]: #if less than 21 and soft stand
            break
        case [True, False, "Stand", "Stand" | True, False, "Stand", "Hit"]: #iff less than 21 and hard stand
            break
```

Comment: Why did you add `[]` to each `case`?

Comment: I saw one example that had it so I tried that. I tried without first.

Comment: Maybe instead of `[a, b, c | x, y, z]` you should try `[a, b, c] | [x, y, z]` or `(a, b, c) | (x, y, z)`. That seems to make more sense to me.

Comment: That looks like that was the issue! That seems to work!  Thank you

Comment: I'm not even sure how `[a, b, c | x, y, z]` is interpreted. I'll wait for someone to explain this in an answer. I would be mostly guessing.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I find the `dis` module useful for these sorts of ambiguity.  in your example it will fail because it can't bind variables `c` and `x`, in OP's case it'll match a 7 element list with either of the two specified constants in the 4th place